# Does pyspark.ml.recommendation.ALS create a pivot table under the hood?

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark, collaborative-filtering, recommendation-engine, als

An ALS recommendation model performs a matrix factorization where it factorizes a matrix of users vs items in latent factors.

A matrix of 3 users and 3 items would look like this:

| users | item_1 | item_2 | item_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user_1 | NA | 4 | 1 |
| user_2 | 4 | 3 | 0 |
| user_3 | NA | 1 | NA |

My dataframe starts such as:

| users | items | rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user_1 | item_2 | 4 |
| user_1 | item_3 | 1 |
| user_2 | item_1 | 4 |
| user_2 | item_2 | 3 |
| user_2 | item_3 | 0 |
| user_3 | item_2 | 1 |

My question is, **before inserting my dataframe in ALS module, do I need to transform it in way where, at the end, I will have a structure such as**:

| users | items | rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user_1 | item_1 | NA |
| user_1 | item_2 | 4 |
| user_1 | item_3 | 1 |
| user_2 | item_1 | 4 |
| user_2 | item_2 | 3 |
| user_2 | item_3 | 0 |
| user_3 | item_1 | NA |
| user_3 | item_2 | 1 |
| user_3 | item_3 | NA |

Or, will, under the hood, [ml.recommendation.ALS](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.recommendation.ALS.html) function create those observations related to the places without interactions? Such as:

| users | items | rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user_1 | item_1 | NA |

If it does not, a way to produce the expected table, would be pivot it and then unpivot it, but it would produce a very huge matrix of users vs items. However, from the [examples presented in the documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.recommendation.ALS.html), it seems that this process (pivot and then, unpivot) is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is **not necessary**.

After you train you the ALS model, the fitted model should be used to **predict** the "missing interactions".

Thus, the term "fill" (in your sentence " ml.recommendation.ALS module fill those missing interactions") is not appropriate, you should uses the term "predict".

Comment: I am not arguing about the output from the predictions of the model, I do know what ALS performs. I'm arguing about the structure of the input in the ALS pyspark function.